# Is this INTERNET REGISTRAR email a phishing scam?

Tags: phishing

I am the "acting" IT person (very loose term) for our small company. I received this email yesterday. I am going to ignore it, but I was just curious how this could negatively effect me/us if I replied to it. I did some searching and found a few similar email reports on this, but no good explanations.

[image]

Comment: The signature block does not list the company, it is addressed to the CEO by title but sent to the tech, and a registrar would know who the contact person was and would be able to properly address the query. What does the header say?

Comment: Looks to me that the chinese want to scare you into buying additional domains to protect your "brand". Its not only ICANN who can play this game.

I've encountered this type of scam before myself.

Also, a guy have a great blogpost about this type of scam: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/spot-chinese-domain-name-scam/

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing that will harm you in responding, but you have to realise that this is a scam and they are trying to get you to respond in order to suck you into their trap. When they respond to your reply, they will ask you to open an attachment, send business details including bank info, or other things that *will* harm you.

When dealing with scams, unless you know what you are doing, it is best not to respond at all else you step onto their slippery slope. Remember, they do this for a living; you're just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Looks really sketchy. 
General rule of thumb is:

*Grammar/Spelling issues + China domain == suspicious at best, malicious/phishing at worst*.

**Recommendation**

Check your domain and registrar information using a tool like:

- `whois <domain>` OR [whois](https://www.whois.net/)
- [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/)

Then contact the Registrar directly.